# Redux-Saga & Redux-Toolkit Wiring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have been trying to introduce redux-sagas and redux-toolkit to my project. It seems that I am having some wiring problems. Not sure how to fix it. Let me know if you have any ideas. Here is the error I am getting. Here is the link to [github](https://github.com/forza11879/twitter-app/tree/master/twitter-app)

[image]

file - **configureAppStore.js**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducer';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import tweetSagas from '../saga/tweet.js';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
const middleware = [...getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }), ...middlewares];

const configureAppStore = () => {
  // reduxjs/toolkit configureStore enables to dispatch async actions
  return configureStore({
    reducer: reducer,
    middleware: middleware,
  });
};

sagaMiddleware.run(tweetSagas);

export default configureAppStore;
```

file - **saga/tweet.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actions from '../store/action/saga.js';
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_PORT;
const hostname = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST;
const baseURL = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;

function api({ dispatch }) {
  return function (next) {
    return function* (action) {
      if (action.type !== actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type) return next(action);
      next(action); // 'sagaApiCallBegan' to show in redux dev tools
      const { url, method, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload;
      try {
        const response = yield call(
          async () =>
            await axios.request({
              baseURL: baseURL,
              url,
              method,
            })
        );
        if (onSuccess)
          yield put(dispatch({ type: onSuccess, payload: response.data }));
      } catch (error) {
        if (onError) yield put(dispatch({ type: onError, payload: error }));
      }
    };
  };
}

function* watchApi() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type, api);
}

const tweetSagas = [fork(watchApi)];

export default tweetSagas;
```

file - **store/tweets.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  sagaApiCallBegan,
  sagaApiCallSuccess,
  sagaApiCallFailed,
} from './action/saga';
import { webSocketCallBegan, webSocketCallFailed } from './action/websocket.js';
import { normalize } from 'normalizr';
import { tweetSchema } from '../store/Schema/tweet.js';

const initialState = () => ({
  byTweetId: {},
  byUserId: {},
  allTweetIds: [],
});

// action, actionTypes and reducer
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'tweets',
  initialState: initialState(),
  // reducers
  reducers: {
    tweetAdded: (state, action) => {
      const { entities, result } = normalize(action.payload, tweetSchema);
      Object.assign(state.byTweetId, entities.byTweetId);
      Object.assign(state.byUserId, entities.byUserId);
      state.allTweetIds.push(result);
    },
    tweetStoreReseted: (state) => initialState(),
  },
});

export const { tweetAdded, tweetStoreReseted } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;

// Action creators
export const fetchTweets = (term) =>
  sagaApiCallBegan({
    url: `/setsearchterm/${term}`,
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: sagaApiCallSuccess.type,
    onError: sagaApiCallFailed.type,
  });

export const fetchTweetsPause = () =>
  sagaApiCallBegan({
    url: '/pause',
    method: 'GET',
    onSuccess: sagaApiCallSuccess.type,
    onError: sagaApiCallFailed.type,
  });

export const getTweet = (message) =>
  webSocketCallBegan({
    message: message,
    onSuccess: tweetAdded.type,
    onError: webSocketCallFailed.type,
  });
```

file - **action/saga.js**

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const sagaApiCallBegan = createAction('saga/apiCallBegan');
export const sagaApiCallSuccess = createAction('saga/apiCallSuccess');
export const sagaApiCallFailed = createAction('saga/apiCallFailed');
```

Comment: seems like issue with `sagaMiddleware.run(tweetSagas)` can you try removeing that and see if it is working? Essentially you are running the sagas before store is mounted.

Answer (score 3):

I created and use [saga-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saga-toolkit) that allows async thunks to get resolved by sagas.

`slice.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { createSagaAction  } from 'saga-toolkit'

const name = 'example'

const initialState = {
  result: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const fetchThings = createSagaAction(`${name}/fetchThings`)

const slice = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchThings.pending]: () => ({
      loading: true,
    }),
    [fetchThings.fulfilled]: ({ payload }) => ({
      result: payload,
      loading: false,
    }),
    [fetchThings.rejected]: ({ error }) => ({
      error,
      loading: false,
    }),
  },
})

export default slice.reducer
```

`sagas.js`

```js
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { takeLatestAsync } from 'saga-toolkit'
import API from 'hyper-super-api'
import * as actions from './slice'

function* fetchThings() {
  const result = yield call(() => API.get('/things'))
  return result
}

export default [
  takeLatestAsync(actions.fetchThings.type, fetchThings),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a point to making your store configuration a function, but you should make sure that you are invoking that function in your `App.jsx` file. I'm not sure if you are as the code is missing here.

Here are some issues I did find that are pretty easy to fix though.

1 Redux sagas uses Generators

```
function api
```

For this function to work it needs to be

```
function* api
```

2. Prioritize the side effect functions over dispatch

```
dispatch(put({ ... })
```

You never need to use `dispatch`. Instead use put or the other side effect functions for dispatching events. Put is a blocking dispatch call. So this code should be

Passing put to dispatch will also cause an error in your app as dispatch always expects an object.

```
yield put({ ... })
```

3. Root sagas are also Generators

```
const tweetSagas = [fork(watchApi)];
```

When making a rootSaga, you need to use the `yield` keyword in front of the `fork` function. A root saga is also a generator function, so this code has to change to the following.

```
export default function* tweetSagas () {
  yield fork(
    watchApi()
  )
}
```

You also have to use the `yield` keyword in front of your fork function. returning a value from generators with sagas won't do you much good.

Comment: thank you for the notes. I did apply the changes. Still trying to debug

Comment: I updated my answer after doing a quick google search. I found the following code sandbox, which seems to work. https://codesandbox.io/s/mfetp?file=/src/store.js:420-666

Comment: i've used it as a guide

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

file - **configureAppStore.js**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducer';
import toast from './middleware/toast.js';
import websocket from './middleware/websocket.js';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import tweetSagas from '../saga/tweet.js';

const configureAppStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, websocket, toast];

  const middleware = [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }),
    ...middlewares,
  ];

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: reducer,
    middleware: middleware,
  });

  sagaMiddleware.run(tweetSagas);

  return store;
};

export default configureAppStore;
```

file - **saga/tweet.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actions from '../store/action/saga.js';
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_PORT;
const hostname = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST;
const baseURL = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;

const fetchApi = async ({ baseURL, url, method }) =>
  await axios.request({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    url: url,
    method: method,
  });

function* api(action) {
  const { url, method, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload;
  const options = {
    baseURL: baseURL,
    url: url,
    method: method,
  };
  try {
    const response = yield call(fetchApi, options);
    if (onSuccess)
      yield put({
        type: onSuccess,
        payload: response.data,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    if (onError) yield put({ type: onError, payload: error });
  }
}

function* watchApi() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.sagaApiCallBegan.type, api);
}

export default function* tweetSagas() {
  yield fork(watchApi);
}
```